# SSIS package running fine on DEV and QA but fails on IAT

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have developed a SSIS package which runs fine on the development and QA environment however fails on IAT. The package is developed on SQL Server 2008 R2.

The configuration of the environments are as follows

```
Dev : The package and database reside on the same box. 65 GB RAM 16 processors. 
QA  :  The package and database are in different boxes. 
       Package  box :  16 GB RAM 4 processors
       Database box :  32 GB RAM 16 processors
IAT :  The package and database are in different boxes. 
       Package  box :  Not sure
       Database box :  32 GB RAM 4 processors
```

Please note the MaxConcurrentExecutables is set to 12. I have in total 17 data flows.

Is the configuration on the package box very important. That's where the package and sql job reside. Not sure why it is failing in IAT ? Could somebody advice

Comment: As I mentioned above the components are split in QA and IAT. It only dev where all the components are in one box

Comment: This can be tricky. What's the error message you're getting ? Are you running them through SQL Server Agent Job ? Did you create proper proxy account and credentials ?

Comment: Yes. I am running them through SQL Server Agent job using proxy account and credentials

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: The last two dataflows that transmit millions of records fails. Get the following error  SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".

Comment: component "OLE DB Source" (1) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202009.